# Unable to display forest plot for met-analysis in R

Tags: r, meta, metafor

I'm not sure why, but I keep getting the error when attempting to generate a forest plot:

**Error in forest.default(sgame) :
Must specify either 'vi', 'sei', or ('ci.lb', 'ci.ub') pairs.**

I looked online extensively to try and figure it out, but have not had any luck. However, I asked someone else to run the code on their computer, and it appears to work for them and a forest plot is generated. Perhaps I installed the packages incorrectly.

whenever I run the metacont() function, I always get the results in the console, but where it messes up is generating the forest plot. Here is the code:

```
library(meta)
library(metafor)
library(dmetar)

Constant

str(Constant)
summary(Constant)

metafinal <- metacont(Ne, Me, Se, Nc, Mc, Sc, data = Constant,
                      studlab = paste(Author), comb.fixed = FALSE,
                      comb.random = TRUE, hakn = TRUE,
                      prediction = FALSE,label.left = "Favors control",
                      label.right = "Favors intervention", sm = "MD")
metafinal

#This is the trouble step where the error occurs
forest(metafinal, layout = "RevMan5", digits.sd = 2)

sgame <- subgroup.analysis.mixed.effects(x=metafinal, subgroups = Constant$Subgroup)

sgame

forest(sgame)
```

Comment: You are loading `metafor` but not actually using it. You don't really need it here, so just remove `library(metafor)`. Or you could do: `meta::forest(metafinal, ...)`.